# Vertically Center Icon with CSS

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I am building a web site. My web site will have blocks of content. Each block will have a title, some text, and an icon. My challenge is, I'm trying to vertically center each icon in the block. Currently, I have the following HTML or you can look at the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dvXBL/).

```
<blockquote>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="small-10 columns">
        <h4>The Block Title</h4>
        <em>Some small blurb</em>
        <p>Here is a paragraph relating to this block. It may include a couple of sentences. These sentences will wrap. Ultimately, the heart needs to be vertically centered.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="small-2 columns">
      <span class="fi-heart" style="font-size:4rem;">&nbsp;</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</blockquote>
```

In this code block, I'm using Zurb Foundation to help with layout. However, I can't seem to get the heart icon to center vertically in my right column. Does anyone know how I can do this with CSS?

Thank you

Comment: Does anyone know how his CSS look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `line-height` property to your inline style for `<span class="fi-heart">` with a value equal to the font-size:

`font-size:4em; line-height: 4em`

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. However, I tried this approach in the Fiddle I provided. Unfortunately this caused the size of the blockquote element to grow. I do not want that to happen. Thank you though.

Comment: And adding `vertical-align: middle` isn't helping?

Comment: No. It is not helping.

Comment: I think one of the things that you need to start with is adding `display: table-cell"` to the `<span class="fi-heart">`. But that will only vertically-align the heart icon based on the `<span>`'s current height. And you want to vertically align based on the left `<span>`'s height. You may need to refactor it so have specific height values applied for both columns.

Comment: That's the only thing I can come up with as well. That or, rely on JavaScript.